# Angles of an incircle

Tags: geometry

> In triangle $ABC$, $\angle BAC = 72^\circ$. The incircle of triangle
> $ABC$ touches sides $BC$, $AC$, and $AB$ at $D$, $E$, and $F$,
> respectively. Find $\angle EDF$, in degrees.

I am currently taking an Intro to Geometry class, and we are learning about incircles/circumcircles, but I don't fully understand them. How would I go about doing this?

I am not looking for a full answer, only a hint in the right direction.

Comment: Can you make a diagram and post it? It always helps!
Once you've done that, try drawing $OD$, $OE$ and $OF$where $O$ is the incenter. What can you say about angles $\widehat{FOD}$ and $\widehat{EOD}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be the incenter of $\triangle ABC$. Then, notice that $AI$ lies on the angle bisector of $\angle BAC$, so $\angle FAI = 72/2 = 36$ degrees. In addition, $\angle AFI = 90$ because $AF$ is tangent to the incircle, so $\angle AIF = 180 - 90 - 36 = 54$ degrees, and similar for $\angle EIA$. Therefore, $\angle FIE = \angle FIA + \angle AIE = 108$.

Now, notice that the measure of $\overset{\Large\frown}{FE}$ is the same as $\angle FIE$, or $108$ degrees. Finally, $\angle FDE$ is half of $\overset{\Large\frown}{FE}$, so $\angle FDE = 108/2 = 54$ degrees.